# How to calculate total in jQuery from JSON

Tags: html, jquery, json

I have a JSON file that contains the price of a product. I need to calculate the price of an individual item and the total price of the item. I succeeded in calculating the individual price of the product, but the final one did not work.
Here is the code jQuery:

```
var cart = {};

function init() {
    $.getJSON("goods.json", goodsOut);
}

function goodsOut(data) {
    var out='';
    for (var key in data) {
        out +='<div class="cart">';
        out +=`<p class="name">${data[key].name}</p>`;
        out +=`<img src="img/${data[key].img}" alt="">`;
        out +=`<div class="cost">${data[key].cost} $</div>`;
        out +=`<button class="add-to-cart" data-id="${key}">Купить</button>`;
        out +='</div>';
    }
    $('.goods-out').html(out);
    $('.add-to-cart').on('click', addToCart);
}

function addToCart() {
    //добавляем товар в корзину
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    if (cart[id]==undefined) {
        cart[id] = 1;
    }
    else {
        cart[id]++;
    }
    showMiniCart();
    saveCart();
}

function saveCart() {
    localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(cart));
}

function showMiniCart() {
    if (!isEmpty(cart)) {
        $('.mini-basket').html('Basket is empty!');
    }
    else {
        $.getJSON('goods.json', function (data) {
            var geds = data;
            var out="";
            for (var key in cart) {
                out += '<div class="mini-basket_list">'
                out += `<img src="img/${geds[key].img}" alt="Error" class="cart-product__img">`;
                out += `<span class="name-basket">${geds[key].name}</span>`+'<br>';
                out += `  <button data-id="${key}" class="plus-goods btn">+</button>  `;
                out += `<span class="quantityy">${cart[key]}</span>`;
                out += `  <button data-id="${key}" class="minus-goods btn">-</button>  `;
                out += `<p class="cost-basket">Цена: <span class="cost-basket_plus">${Number(cart[key])*Number(geds[key].cost)}</span> $</p>`;
                out += `<button data-id="${key}" class="del-goods btn">x</button>  `;
                out += '</div>'
            }
            $('.mini-basket').html(out);
            $('.del-goods').on('click', delGoods);
            $('.plus-goods').on('click', plusGoods);
            $('.minus-goods').on('click', minusGoods);
        });
    }
}

function delGoods() {
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    delete cart[id];
    saveCart();
    showMiniCart();
}
function plusGoods() {
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    cart[id]++;
    saveCart();
    showMiniCart();
}
function minusGoods() {
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    if (cart[id]==1) {
        delete cart[id];
    }
    else {
        cart[id]--;
    }
    saveCart();
    showMiniCart();
}

function loadCart() {
    if (localStorage.getItem('cart')) {
        cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart'));
        showMiniCart();
    }
}

function isEmpty(object) {
    for (var key in object)
    if (object.hasOwnProperty(key)) return true;
    return false;
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    init();
    loadCart();
});
```

Here is the code JSON:

```
{
    "1234": {
      "name": "Aplle",
      "cost": "5",
      "img" : "apple.png"
    },
    "1235": {
      "name": "Cherry",
      "cost": "7",
      "img" : "cherry.png"
    },
    "1236": {
      "name": "Grape",
      "cost": "10",
      "img" : "grape.png"
    },
    "1237": {
      "name": "Slice of watermelon",
      "cost": "12",
      "img" : "watermelon.png"
    }
  }
```

Here is the code HTML:

```
<body>

<header class="header">
    <nav class="nav">
        <div class="basket">
            <div class="cart__text">
                Basket
            </div>
            <div class="cart-content">
                <div class="block" data-simplebar>
                    <div class="mini-basket">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="cart-content__bottom">
                    <div class="cart-content__fullprice">
                        <span>Total: </span>
                        <span class="fullprice"></span> <!--Here I want to display a total-->
                        <span>$</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>

<section>
    <div class="goods-out"></div>
</section>

<script src="js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/simplebar.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
```

Total should be shown in a span with fullprice class.

Comment: PS... `out += out += out +=` no. Just use `out += \`\`` one single time.  That's exactly the problem Template Literals are meant to solve! https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: This is not a JSON problem. `data` is an object. The origin of that data (actual JSON) is not relevant for the question.